# Specify Framework Version for CSharpCompilation.Emit

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Does anyone know whether it is possible to specify the Framework-Version when Emitting assemblies using CSharpCompilation's extensionmethod Emit?

We need to target 4.5.1 apparently since otherwise we get a nasty runtime error:

```
MissingMethodException
Method not found: '!!0[] System.Array.Empty()'.
```

Or do we have to wait till clients are upgraded to Framework 4.6 before we can make use of Roslyn?

Comment: FWIW: If you need to convince your clients to update, Microsoft is dropping support for 4.5.1 on January 12, 2016: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1.aspx

Comment: @JoshVarty that is indeed some important information. Im glad you wrote this, we totally oversaw this announcement from MS. **edit** if this sounds ironic, it is not supposed to.

Comment: @CSharpie, what do you mean by "target"? 4.x frameworks all target the 4.0 runtime. What code throws that exception and doesn't throw for 4.52, 4.6 or 4.6.1?

Comment: Array.Empty() is documented as a .NET 4.6 method.  No, you cannot force anybody to target that version.  Cast the version you are willing to support into stone and only generate code that is compatible with that version.  Do keep in mind that the end-of-support statement only applies to the *installed* .NET version, it has nothing to do with the targeting pack that the client programmer wants to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler doesn't (and has never) had a concept of "framework version". All the compiler understands is what set of references are included. It sounds like you are creating your compilation with references to 4.6 versions of the framework (possibly because you are using running assembly locations, and are running on 4.6).

Instead, you'll need to ensure that you have the 4.5.1 targeting pack installed (VS install does this automatically, but other machines may not have it), and add its references to your compilation from out of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies`.

The compiler will emit references to `Array.Empty` if it exists in the referenced assemblies, but has fallback logic if it doesn't.

Comment: I was kind of expecting an answer like this but i couldnt figure it out myself. Many thanks. So i need to include references from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1
I was doing typeof(object).Assembly.Location before.